# Find elements which are present in the first array and not in the second

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

How can I find a numbers not present in a second array from given two arrays in C++?

For Example:

input:

```
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100

10 20 30 40 50 50 40 30 20 10
```

output:

```
60 70 80 90 100
```

---

input:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

-1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10
```

output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

---

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const int n = 10;
    int arr1[n];
    const int m = 10;
    int arr2[n];
    int uncommon = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        std::cin >> arr1[i];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
    {
        std::cin >> arr2[j];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
        {
            if (arr1[i] == arr2[j])
                uncommon++;
        }
        if (uncommon == 0)
            std::cout << arr1[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code? What issues are you having?

Comment: use `set` or `unordered_set`.

Comment: What is `count`? Is that a typo?

Comment: its a mistake ))

Comment: If the arrays are sorted, look at [`std::set_difference()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference): "*Copies the elements from the sorted range `[first1, last1)` which are not found in the sorted range `[first2, last2)` to the range beginning at `d_first`.*"

Comment: This is basically a set theory problem where you need to ```A - B```. Here ```A``` and ```B``` are sets.

Answer (score 2):

Usage of [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and [std::set_difference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference)  can be used to output the difference in the two arrays:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 };
    int b[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10 };

    // sort the two arrays
    std::sort(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
    std::sort(std::begin(b), std::end(b));

    // get the set_difference and output the results
    std::set_difference(std::begin(a), std::end(a),
        std::begin(b), std::end(b), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Output:

```
60 70 80 90 100
```

Answer (score 0):

I kinda forgot c++, but here's psudo-code (actually, javascript):

```
notPresent=[];
for(i=0;i<array1.length;i++) {
  found=false;
  for(j=0;j<array2.length && !found;j++) {
    if(array1[i]==array2[j]) found=true;
  };
  if(!found) {
    notPresent.push(array1[i]);
  }
}
```

The idea is: loop over elements of 1st array and compare to all elements of 2nd array (and stop once found), and if not found: missing value, as requested, push to notPresent array.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please select and up-vote it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I offer this solutions :

1. **Runtime** : O(n * m), n - size of arr1, m - size of arr2. **Memory** : O(1)
   **Idea**: First loop goes for elements in arr1 and second loop for elements in arr2. If elements match then you can change element in arr1 with value(may be -1 000 000 or another value) which will tell you that this element is presented in arr2. Example:
   arr1 : [1, 2, 3], arr2 : [10, 12 ,1]. Then after the solution arr1 would be: [-1000000, 2, 3]. It doesn't require an extra memory because you do all operations in place.

**Code**:

```
int main()
{
    const int n = 10;
    int arr1[n], arr2[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        { 
        std::cin >> arr1[i]; 
        }
    for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
        std::cin >> arr2[j];
        }
    const int value = -1000000; // Better to use INT_MAX or INT_MIN
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; ++j) // You should iterate through all elements 
                                  //in arr2 which size is m.
            if(arr1[i] == arr2[j])
                arr1[i] = value; 
        }
    // Print elements which is in arr1 and not in arr2
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
           std::cout << arr1[i] << ' ';
       }
}
```

2. **Runtime** : O(n*m). **Memory** : O(size of elements which is in arr1 and not in arr2)
   **Idea:** The same here, Create an array which shows you which elements are in arr1 and not in arr2. Then iterate through elements of arr1 and compare with elements of arr2. If element didn't match with every elements of arr2 you can savely push it to arr1.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    const int n = 10;
    int arr1[n], arr2[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        { 
        std::cin >> arr1[i]; 
        }
    for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
        std::cin >> arr2[j];
        }
    vector<int> Array;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        int flag = 0; // flag initially 0 for every element in arr1
        for(int j = 0; j < m; ++j){
            if(arr1[i] == arr2[j])  // If it's match you make flag = 1
                flag = 1;
        }
        if (flag == 0){    // It shows you that where wasn't match
            Array.push_back(arr1[i]);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Array.size(); i++){
        std::cout << Array[i] << ' ';
    }
         
}
```

3. **Runtime** : O(n) + O(m). **Memory**: O(n)
   **Idea: ** Use data structure map. (To understand it I would recommend you to search in youtube. There are a lot of good videos). Try to think and implement yourself)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for memory efficient solution i.e. O(1) for memory, then you can sort the second array and for each element in first array find whether it's present in second array or not through binary search. Time complexity : `O(mlogm + nlogm)` where n is size of first array and m is size of second array.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    const int n = 10;
    int arr1[n], arr2[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        { 
        std::cin >> arr1[i]; 
        }
    for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
        std::cin >> arr2[j];
        }
 
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
        int j;
        for(j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            if(arr1[i] == arr2[j])
                break;
            if(j == n)
            std::cout << arr1[i] << " ";
        }
}
```